# systemd timer enabled but status is inactive

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

How can I get the following timer to start automatically? Right now the timer only works if I do `systemctl start while-test.timer`. Otherwise, eventhough I enabled the timer, it does not start automatically. Even after doing `systemctl daemon-reload` or rebooting.

```
while-test .service
-------------------
[Unit]
Description=While loop test script

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/user/bash/while-test.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

and

```
while-test .timer
----------------
[Unit]
Description=While loop test script timer

[Timer]
OnCalendar=Mon *-*-* 10:52:00
Unit=while-test.service

[Install]
WantedBy=default.service
```

Comment: What is the output of `systemctl --all list-timers`? Are the timer and unit user specific or system wide?

Comment: Based on a previous question, can you look at the journal? You should see a few log lines under `sudo systemctl status while-test.timer` (the sudo may be required to get the logs), or you can use `journalctl -b -u while-test.timer`

Answer (score 4):

Although it may not be the cause for the OP's issue, I had the exact same problem this week and in my case the cause was storing the true unit files on a drive partition
that was mounted at boot after systemd loaded the timers (pointing to them with symlinks).

In fact, inspecting my systemd log (with journalctl -b) actually showed that
the partition was being mounted ~0.01 seconds immediately after the timers were loaded.
Rather it tried to load the timers but complained (in the log) that the files did not exist.

So just like in OP's case, I could manually start the timers fine after my system was up and running, but they wouldn't auto start at boot like they were supposed to.

For any variations of the same problem, I anticipate checking the log is likely to help the diagnosis.

> I noticed the other answer on this page seems to infer the step of enabling the  service along with the timer. There's a different stack exchange answer somewhere that regarded that step as superfluous or possibly confounding since it would presumably achieve the effect of auto starting the service like a normal daemon when the timer is supposed to be in control of it.

Comment: Agreed, enabling the service as well would make it start/run at boot, as well as when the timer starts/runs it on its schedule.

Answer (score 3):

```
systemctl enable while-test.service
systemctl enable while-test.timer
```

You may need to run these with sudo. This enables the service and timer at boot. Verify that it is enabled with:

```
systemctl list-timers
```

This will show status information like next run time, last run time, last passed run, and the service it activates.